# Как сделать круглую кнопку с картинкой Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-button

Имеется кнопка:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/account"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.049"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.056"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
```

Она уже круглая, как добавить на нее картинку?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужна кнопка с картинкой, а значит необходимо использовать `ImageButton`.
Где вы примените форму и вставите картинку с помощью `android:src=`

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно именно с Button, можешь использовать параметр foreground. Данный параметр растянет переданную картинку под размер вьюхи и нарисует её поверх.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:foreground="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
```

Выглядит в данном случае примерно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]